# How to group axis into two set in syntagmatic parallel-coordinates plot (D3 js)

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

[image]

I have a requirement where I need to group the axis into sets. Although I have tried this successfully using pure D3, I need this using your parallel-coordinates library.

Comment: Welcome to SO. However you won't get much response with very broad requests like this. Please edit your question to show what you have tried and rephrase your question as something specfic so that you can get a clear answer (at the moment it sounds a bit like 'please write my code for me', I am sure that is not what you meant, but we get a lot of that and people may just skip over genuine requests for help if it looks similar.)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.